# how to create a function with the given inputs and outputs

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

I created a table of inputs and outputs:

\begin{array}{c|c}
 x-coordinate & no. of lattice points \\
\hline 
0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \\
2 & 2 \\
3 & 2 \\
4 & 3 \\
5 & 3 \\
6 & 4 \\
7 & 4 \\
8 & 5 \\
\end{array}

I know that there will be $2014$ lattice points if the $x-$coordinate is $2014$ and there will be $2014$ lattice points if the the $x-$coordinate is $2015$.

I'm learning about difference tables and while I know that you can't use that approach here, I wanted to know if there is any other methodical way of creating a function that models this..

I just was looking at the pattern and figured it out but I'm wondering how i could solve it if there was a more "complicated" pattern that couldn't be modeled with a linear, quadratic or polynomial function.

This is an example of a more "complicated" question:

[image]

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
 (x)& f(x) & \Delta_{1} & \Delta_{2}\\
\hline 
1 & 6 & 14 & 8\\
2 & 20 & 22 & 8\\
3 & 42 & 30\\ 
4 & 72 \\
\end{array}

The function that models this is $f(x)=4x^2+2x=2x(2x+1)$

$f(2014)=2(2014)*[(2*2014+1)] = 16228812$

Comment: I'm sure you noticed that the pattern is basically $\lfloor \frac{x}{2} \rfloor + 1.$ What do you mean by the last question if there was a more complicated pattern? Do you mean for an arbitrary sequence of numbers $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ can we find a function $f$ that maps $a_n \mapsto b_n$?

Comment: thanks, i added what i consider to be a more "complicated" question.

Answer (score 1):

At point $(+2014,+2014)$ we count $(2\times2014+1)^2$ points.

At Point $(-2014,+2014)$ we just don't count points $(t,+2014)$ for $(-2013 \leqslant t 
\leqslant +2014)$ that is $4028$ points. So the answer is:
$$(2\times2014+1)^2-4028-1=16228812$$
The last minus $1$ is for that the length between two points is ONE.

If want a function for it:
$$l(n,m) = \left\{\begin{array}{c} (2n-1)^2+(n-m)-1 & -n \leqslant m \leqslant n-1 \\ (2m+1)^2-(3m+n)-1 & m \leqslant n \leqslant -m \\ (2n+1)^2-(5n-m)-1 & n \leqslant m \leqslant -n \\ (2m-1)^2+(7m+n)-1 & -m \leqslant n \leqslant m \\ (2n+1)^2-1 & 1 \leqslant m = n \\ \end{array}\right\}$$

Comment: i dont think that is correct, the solution manual says 16228812. I created a finite difference table for all coordinates that have the form $(-a,a)$

Comment: Yes, You are right. I made a mistake just in replacing the numbers. But you should follow the solution explanations, NOT ONLY THE FINAL NUMBER! I edit my answer.

Comment: i added my solution

Comment: I add a function to my answer.